# change the url background color (when get tapped) from gray to others

Tags: html, url, background

It could be a HTML question as well...

I have a UIWebView with a page (from the hand made html string) loaded. For the url link on the page, if you tap on it, it has gray as background, which I think is the default behavior on iPhone.

Is there a way to programmingly (thru javascript) change that to be other colors, say, blue? It doesn't seem to work for me anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via CSS (no javascript is necessary) using the following rule:

```
a {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: blue;
}
```

Additional information can be found on the [Apple Developer site](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/AdjustingtheTextSize/AdjustingtheTextSize.html)